# Memory allocation and deletion in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

What is the difference between: double deletion, memory leak, and deletion of stack memory? What are the conditions that cause each of these errors? I ask this in reference to question 5 [on this test](http://courses.skule.ca/exams/custom/20089/ECE244_2008_ts_1288731279.pdf). I'm not too familiar with what is good practice vs. bad practice when it comes to this stuff, so any guidelines/tips are appreciated!

Comment: None of these are good practice.  If you're taking a test, maybe we shouldn't be answering these questions for you.

Comment: "in C" - but the question is tagged "C++". Now what?

Comment: It seems like you're being tested on your knowledge and that you don't know anything so should fail the test!

Comment: Always cheat, do it well and you will become manager in sales department, if you learn it then you will become average Dilbert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced link has a test with answers already on it, so I don't think further clarifying the test's answers will be helping to cheat.

A correct program will always execute exactly one call to delete for each call to new.  All of these things are violations of this rule.

A double deletion calls delete more than once.

```
A* p = new A;
if ( someOption )
    delete p;

... more code ...
delete p;    // p is double freed if someOption is true
return;
```

A memory leak doesn't call delete at all.

```
A* p = new A;
if ( someOption )
    delete p;    // p leaked if someOption is not true
return;
```

And deletion of stack memory calls delete on memory that was not returned from new.

```
A a;

A* p;
if ( someOption )
    p = &a;
else
    p = new A;

delete p;    // p is deletion of stack memory if someOption is true
```